Entry Door Casing for Uneven Brick
The brick walls on my entry door are extremely out of plumb, so it doesn't fit very nicely inside the brick.
I'm looking for some ideas on how to finish the casing. The only thing I can think of is to either taper the trim or build the jamb extension out more and secure it to the face of the house.
I appreciate any help. Thanks!


Given there's perhaps a quarter-brick difference in height at the top, the wonkiness will be visible whatever you do.
Trimming on the face of the brick is likely going to be the best look, but it's still going to be evident, so trimming inside the opening is not really worse - the house is a bit wonky, and that's the way it is, unless you're going to rebuild it to "solve" an appearance issue. Old houses are usually not particularly plumb, square, or level.
One potential approach would be to make the surface trim cartoonishly not rectangular boards in an exaggerated way, which would tend to disguise the actual wonkiness with intentional wonkiness, but that's a personal taste decision as much as anything.
You could also use contrasting color, with trim to fill the gap, and the amount of that trim that is the minimum space painted white (or whatever your final trim color is to be) as rectangular, plumb/level bits; and the remaining wedge-shaped bits dark, or brick-colored, or otherwise visually de-emphasized from 10 feet away. Bright yellow foam catches the eye a great deal more in the present state.

You could take the time to scribe wood trim to match the actual shape of the opening, just as one scribes face frames to fit "built in" furniture to interior walls which aren't plumb, level, or square... Or nail the trim up so it overlaps into the door frame and then trim it even using a guided router bit, then use flexible molding to hide some of the remaining unevenness at the brick edge, or combine the two.
